# C++ including doesn't work

Tags: c++, include

On the last several hours I'm trying desperately to figure out what is wrong, but in vain:

I have the following scenario: I had a working header, and I decided to move parts from it to a new another file.

So basically I have now:

**FileA**

```
......
class A;
.....
```

**File B**

```
#include FileA
.....
A B;
.....
```

But the variable `A` doesn't get recognized in fileB at all.

- All the definitions are under the same namespace
- Nothing is misspelled
- I'm using in the boost library and on debug mode I get : "intelisence: incompatible build options" (dont know yet if this connected or not to my problem)
- When looking on the code, the visual studio recognized all the types (i.e. when pressing on the type "A" in file B, the visual studio recognized it).

What am I doing wrong?

Following you request for the real code and further details:
Let me be more specific 
I'm using the ifndef method and probably this causing to the mess, but I dont see why since fileB is the only one who includes fileA

The code itself looks like this:

```
    #ifndef MERKLE_BASICS_HPP
    #define MERKLE_BASICS_HPP
    #include "FullProofConsumer.hpp"
    #include <openssl\sha.h>
    namespace PCP_Project{
typedef unsigned char* HashDigest;
//Forward Declarations
HashDigest hashTwoElements(HashDigest,HashDigest);
HashDigest hash_GF2E_Element (GF2E);
HashDigest createZeroCommitment();
//The definition of the hashDigest type, for now its just long. Will be probably       replacedlater. 
//typedef unsigned char* HashDigest;

     }
    #endif
```

And then on the other file I have:

```
                #ifndef MERKLE_CONSUMER
                #define MERKLE_CONSUMER
                #include <fstream>
                #include "MerkleBasics.hpp"
                 namespace PCP_Project{
                 ......

                 HashDigest Value;
                  ...
```

And the compilation Error: 
Error   273 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Value'
(I have plenty of those, this is just one example)
Sorry if from the original question you understood something defferent, and thanks again

Comment: Please edit your question to include your *actual* code.

Comment: Please show actual code and actual compiler messages.

Comment: This new code works fine for me - after edits of course. Post **minimum compilable code** that exibits the issue please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in file A, you only have a forward declaration of the class:

```
class A;
```

That means you don't have a complete definition of the class, and thus unable to use instances of it - you can however use pointers.

You'll have to post more code for more help (properly formatted).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the description of your problem I take a random guess - have you by accident placed the SAME INCLUDE GUARDS in both the files ? In that case the include A will not work at all.

Comment: Guessing is pointless here; we should wait for the OP to include his/her actual code.